# How to get full points in a SuperTuxKart Challenge(Story Mode)

Tags: supertuxkart

When I complete a challenge in SuperTuxKart Story Mode, I always win 6/8 points. The game says:

> You completed the easy challenge! Points earned on this level: 6/8

I am wondering why I only get 6 points out of 8? I am winning each race an average of 30 seconds ahead of all the AI karts, and skidding like a pro! Is it because I sometimes go off the track, or because I should stay closer to the other karts?
Or it is because I am in Novice mode and will get more points if I do the challenge in Intermediate or Expert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get more points for completing the challenges in higher-level modes, such as Intermediate or Expert. If you win the race in Intermediate mode, you will get 7/8 points, and if you win in Expert mode you will get 8/8 points.